# Power calculation to test different intercepts in simple linear regression

Tags: regression, statistical-power, intercept

I have two groups of data: patients and healthy controls. I perform a measurement and a modelled estimation of this measurement on both groups. I then calculate using simple linear regression ($y = b\cdot x+a$) what the slope ($b$) and intercept ($a$) are for both the patients and controls, so I have two simple linear regression lines. I want to do a power calculation to determine the sample sizes of both groups to show/test whether the intercepts ($a$'s) of the patients and controls are different or not. I.e. if the intercept of one group's regression line is significantly lower or higher than the intercept of the other group's regression line.

I know very little about size and power calculation: I only know what it's used for, but not how it's done. I want to know how I can do such a calculation in my particular situation: what do I need to know up front; how do I calculate the necessary sample size? If possible, please explain why certain steps and assumptions need to be taken, because I want to understand this subject better.